# Join com lambda expression apenas

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Com LINQ sem problemas. Agora, como eu faço um `join` com duas ou mais tabelas? Abaixo a tentativa do `join` que eu não consegui ir até o fim. Duas tabelas(`T_Acao` e `T_ProximaAcao`). Campo no `join` é o `IDAcao`

```
var resultadoAcao = (db.T_Acao
                                    .Where(a => a.IDAcao == 7)
                                    .Join(db.T_ProximaAcao, p => p.IDAcao )
                                );
```

Como termino esse join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido. Um colega me passou:

```
var resultadoAcao = (db.T_Acao.Join(
                                    db.T_ProximaAcao,
                                    t1 => t1.IDAcao,
                                    t2 => t2.IDAcao,
                                    (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2})
                                    .Where( a => a.t1.IDAcao == 7)
                                     .Select(i => new {acao = i.t1.Acao, proximaacao = i.t2.ProximaAcao})
                                ).ToList();
```

Comment: Peço que por favor aceite sua resposta para que a pergunta não mais figure como "sem resposta". Obrigado!

Comment: Eu sei, só que o SOPT só libera para aceitar a minha resposta após dois dias.